# Does the @BeforeAll in cucumber runs before spring application context is loaded?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

1. I am trying to use initialising bean and bean with post contruct has its properties null.
2. And also I am not able to accessing application.yml property through @value annotation

So I suspect that the applicationContext is not loaded. How to verify that and what to do now?

I basically want to make a rest call in before all.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your problem. Do you have an MCVE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I agree with M.P. Korstanje. This is a very low-quality question. You need to provide more details as well as minimal, reproducible code.

Comment: Have you tried putting `System.out` statements in your code to see the order of execution of these methods? That would be a start.